# query for retrieving information from 3 tables in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

i have 3 tables

```
1)
news_table
nid     tilte
1       Hi
2       Hello

2)
Product_table 
pid     name 
2       abc  
3       def  
4       rty  
5       zxc  
6       poj  
7       lkj  

3)
temp
nid     pid 
1       2  
1       3  
1       4  
2       5  
2       6  
2       7
```

I want output like this

```
nid     pids    names           title  
1       2,3,4   abc,def,rtj     hi 
2       5,6,7   zxc,poj,lkj     hello
```

Comment: mysql <> sql server. which one are you using? also please add what have you tried so far

Comment: sql server.... i got it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a full working example run on `SQL Server 2012`:

```
DECLARE @news_table TABLE
(
    [nid] TINYINT
   ,[title] VARCHAR(8)
);

INSERT INTO @news_table ([nid], [title])
VALUES (1, 'Hi')
      ,(2, 'Hellow');

DECLARE @Product_table TABLE
(
    [pid] TINYINT
   ,[name] VARCHAR(8)
);

INSERT INTO @Product_table ([pid], [name])
VALUES (2, 'abc')
      ,(3, 'def')
      ,(4, 'rty')
      ,(5, 'zxc')
      ,(6, 'poj')
      ,(7, 'lkj');

DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
   [nid] TINYINT
  ,[pid] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @temp ([nid], [pid])
VALUES (1, 2)
      ,(1, 3)
      ,(1, 4)
      ,(2, 5)
      ,(2, 6)
      ,(2, 7);

SELECT [nid]
      ,[pids]
      ,[names]
      ,[title]
FROM @news_table NT
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + PT.[name]
            FROM @temp T
            INNER JOIN @Product_table PT
                ON T.[pid] = PT.[pid]
            WHERE T.[nid] = NT.[nid]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    )
) DS1 ([names])
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + CAST(T.[pid] AS VARCHAR(12))
            FROM @temp T
            WHERE T.[nid] = NT.[nid]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    )
) DS2 ([pids]);
```

[image]

---

I will strongly recommend to check the following links about `.net` integration in `SQL Server`:

- [String Utility Functions Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx) - full working examples
- [Stairway  to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/)  - still in progress
- [Introduction to SQL Server CLR Integration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.110).aspx) - official documentation

You can defined your own aggregates. For example, for concatenating strings and the solution will be far more simple:

```
SELECT NT.[nid]
      ,[dbo].[Concatenate] (T.[pid]) AS [pids]
      ,[dbo].[Concatenate] ([name]) AS [names]
      ,NT.[title]
FROM @news_table NT
INNER JOIN @temp T
    ON T.[nid] = NT.[nid]
INNER JOIN @Product_table PT
    ON T.[pid] = PT.[pid]
GROUP BY NT.[nid]
        ,NT.[title]
```